# React/redux errors cause routes to fail

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a React/Redux app in production that talks to an API. In a few situations the app will error as a result of data from the API (that we are unable to entirely control) and when this happens it takes down the entire react-router route.

We are using PropTypes as recommended in the [Redux real-world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/components/User.js#L19-L25) but these do not help in production. Is there a way to prevent these errors from taking down the entire route, and log the exception?

Comment: Any chance you can post up samples of the API calls and specifically the results from it that cause the failures?

Comment: The API calls themself do not fail (apologies for the vagueness) - it's the data within the API calls. Our app isn't fully taking into account the **shape** of the data. For example, we expect arrays and objects, but sometimes with keys that may or may not be present.

Comment: Sounds like a pain!  Which is it though, array irregularities or object, key based ones (or both)?

Comment: lol, take your pick - some objects and keys we can depend upon, but some apparently are questionable. I understand that addressing this on the API side is the "correct" approach, but I am wondering if it's possible to raise exceptions without try/catch around every single component/function.

Comment: If it's dodgy data with arrays I wouldn't touch it.  IMHO Missing keys are the **_lesser_** evil  _if_ you can use `Object.assign`, or `spread syntax` or similar.  Definitely not painless.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense - I was wondering if there was a technique I was unaware of. The pattern of using PropTypes to verify shape in development seems useful - it'd be great if there was a way to leverage this in prod. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

React will probably get error boundaries soon, as discussed in [the issue #2461](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461).

Somebody in that thread [built a workaround](https://gist.github.com/Aldredcz/4d63b0a9049b00f54439f8780be7f0d8) until the feature is officially supported.

I hope this helps you for your use case.

Comment: I've tried it in a quick [code pen](http://codepen.io/amann/pen/RoJbrM?editors=0010#0) and it seems to work well (look at the three classes at the very bottom of the JS file).